# Problem modifying PATH variable in fish config

Tags: shell, fish

I have the following configuration in ~/.config/fish/conf.d/python.fish:

```
# Initialise pyenv if found
echo "Running python config"
if status --is-interactive && test -d "$HOME/.pyenv"
    echo "Inside pyenv if"
    set -pxg PATH $HOME/.pyenv/bin $HOME/.pyenv/shims
    source ("$HOME/.pyenv/bin/pyenv" init - | psub)
    echo "End pyenv if"
end

# Poetry settings
if status --is-interactive && test -d "$HOME/.pyenv"
    set -xg POETRY_VIRTUALENVS_IN_PROJECT 1
    set -xg POETRY_VIRTUALENVS_CREATE 1
    set -pxg PATH $HOME/.poetry/bin
end
echo "End python config"
```

Every single echo command in the configuration is executed when I am creating a new shell, but the PATH variable is not modified. However, the POETRY_ variables show up as expected.

But things work as expected if I source the file in an existing shell with

```
source ~/.config/fish/conf.d/python.fish
```

What could possibly be wrong here?

Update: The problem only occurs inside of tmux, and not when I am starting terminals like Alacritty or Kitty. But all echo commands is still run inside tmux.

Comment: This looks fine to me. Maybe try running with fish_trace set, e.g. `fish_trace=1 fish`. That will print all the commands which are run, perhaps something else is messing with PATH. Does that give any clues?

Comment: If you are on Debian or a derivative (like Ubuntu): https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=1000829 or https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=1001584

Comment: I now see that the problem only occurs inside of tmux, and not when I start any terminals.

Comment: @H.A Tmux starts a login shell by default, which still triggers the Debian patch. It's a distro problem.

Comment: @faho Thanks! I am using Debian Testing. But why is not this triggered for Kitty or Alacritty?

Comment: Because they don't start login shells. Debian's patch is only triggered for login shells (they've attempted to recreate bash's default path setup).

Answer (score 0):

This was a Debian bug - they added configuration that reset $PATH, and it happened after the user's configuration snippets but before config.fish.

This appears to be fixed in Debian: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=1000199. Now they merely *add* the default directories instead of replacing $PATH entirely.

Because config.fish is read after all the conf.d files, you can always use config.fish to override anything done in the snippets, like if your vendor breaks things.